# Making a join with Eloquent based on a list of ids

Tags: php, mysql, join, orm, eloquent

I have set up two Eloquent models with a `belongsToMany` relation in both directions. This works perfectly fine but now I need to make a more detailed query within the relationship. To keep things simple, let's say the tables have the following columns:

```
wigs:
- id
- name
- type

heads:
- id
- name

heads_wigs:
- head_id
- wig_id
```

Now I need to fetch a series of `wigs` with a given `type` within a list of given `head` `id`'s. So what I have is:

- a `wig` `type`
- an array with `head` `id`'s

I am using Eloquent outside of laravel so I want to start building the ORM query on the model. Something like:

```
Wig::where( 'type', $type )-> ... //here the code to make the join on head id's
```

This is where my understanding of SQL lacks but I suppose this should not be too hard to achieve.

**UPDATE:**

To rephrase it in a sentence: `get all wigs with type=wig_type that have a belongsToMany relationship with the heads [1,2,3,5,6,8,9]`. I want to end up with a collection of `wigs` by performing a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
Head::whereIn('id', $head_id_array)->load(['wig' => function($query) use ($wig_type) {
        $query->where('type', $wig_type);
}])->get();
```

or

```
Wig::where('type', $wig_type)->load(['heads' => function($query) use ($head_id_array) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $head_id_array);
}])->get();
```

if I understand your question correctly.

Or

```
$wig = Wig::where('type', $wig_type)->get();
$heads = $wig->heads()->whereIn('id', $head_id_array)->get();
$matching_head_ids = $heads->lists('id');
$wig->matching_head_ids = $matching_head_ids;
```

That way, the wig object returned will have an array of matching head ids.

you could put this in a method on your wig model:

```
class Wig extends Eloquent {
    public function heads()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Head');
    }

    /**
     * @param array $head_ids    Provided head id array
     * @return array             Array of this wigs head id's which match the provided head ids
     */
    public function matchingHeadIds($head_ids)
    {
        return $this->heads()->whereIn('id', $head_ids)->get()->lists('id');
    }
}
```

then use it like so

```
$wig = Wig::where('type', $wig_type);
$wig->matchingHeadIds($head_ids);
```

---

Edit

This is not a simple task for an ORM like eloquent, since it treats each record like a row from the table, so something like this wouldn't work:

```
$wigs = Head::whereIn('id', $head_ids)->wigs()->where('type', $wig_type)->get();
```

There is a [whereHas](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations) method available which you can use like so:

```
Wig::where('type', $wig_type)->whereHas('heads', function ($query) use ($head_ids) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $head_ids);
})->get();
```

which should give you the results you need.

Comment: That's not quite what I am aiming for. I'll try to rephrase it in a sentence: `get all wigs with type=wig_type that have a belongsToMany relationship with the heads [1,2,3,5,6,8,9]`. I want to end up with a collection of `wigs` by performing a single query.

Comment: I have revised my answer.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. The `whereHas` method seems the most logical to me, now I jut need to check which one gives the best performance.